# Can I use less values in IN clause in SQL than the subquery contains?

Tags: sql

For example:

```
Select...
FROM...
WHERE street IN (
    SELECT street, country
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
);
```

Here we have only 1 value before IN (that is "street") and the subquery have "street" and "country". My question is, can I do that kind of thing?

I have a side question:
Can I use MAX(...) inside WHERE clause?
Can I use data that are not in SELECT clause? Like:

SELECT data.person, data.city

FROM data

WHERE MAX(data.number)

GROUP BY city

We have person, city as a candidate key. Than the output of the query would be the city with its respective person that have the highest number.

Comment: What is the purpose of the country column in the subquery?

Comment: No and I do not see how it would make sense (the types of both operands are different: string pair (?) vs string) but with some databases, you are allowed to do `[...] WHERE (street, country) IN (SELECT street, country [...])`

Comment: its just an example, I just want to know if that is a valid syntax

Comment: Nop, you have to use WHERE street IN (
    SELECT street
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...

Comment: There are some SQL platforms that let you compare multiple columns in a match but even then it would have to be the same number of columns on each side. I'm guessing that you envision that it would only use the first column and ignore the rest. I'm not sure what scenario you have where that would be handy but I would say that's not quite in the "spirit" of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you provided is not valid SQL because the subquery used in the IN clause is selecting two columns (street and country). The IN clause expects a subquery to return a single column of values.

If you want to filter rows from the main table  for example (addresses) based on the combination of street and country from the subquery (valid_streets), you should use the EXISTS or JOIN clause. Here's an example using EXISTS:

```
SELECT *
FROM addresses a
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM valid_streets v
    WHERE v.street = a.street
      AND v.country = a.country
      AND condition
);
```

```
SELECT a.*
FROM addresses a
JOIN valid_streets v ON a.street = v.street AND a.country = v.country
WHERE condition;
```

I hope it will help you to understand, shortly explain, you cannot search or filter one dimension array into two columns

Comment: Actually, tuple comparison is possible according to SQL standard and many RDBMS implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter on two columns, you can use an `inner join`:

```
SELECT  t1.*
FROM    ... AS t1
JOIN    (
        SELECT  ...
        FROM    ...
        ) AS t2
ON      t1.street = t2. street
        AND t1.country = t2.country
```

This query will return rows from the table aliased as `t1` that match a street/country combination from the subquery aliased as `t2`.